# Enabling installments for a PayPal Checkout

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm using paypal's react library, and I need to add installments option, can someone help me on how to do it?

```
  function createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            value: "1000.00",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merchant-provided installments you're interested in are available exclusively for MXN transactions to an MX account (meses sin intereses), or BRL transactions to a BR account (parcelamentos).  So begin by specifying the correct `currency_code` in the `amount` object of your example code, since it will default to 'USD' otherwise.

Assuming this is sandbox mode, verify that the receiver account you are using is of the correct country MX or BR country in: [Sandbox Accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts), and that that account is being used for the client id of the APP you've created and are using in: [My Apps & Credentials](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).

Next you need to enable installments on the receiver account. Find the option [here for sandbox mode](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan), or [here for live mode](https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan).

When testing the checkout, you must enter or select a credit card that starts with a BIN that is eligible for installments. For sandbox you can [generate numbers here](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2FcreditCardGenerator%2F), ensuring you select the correct Country from the list.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I activated the installments usingi the following pages:
For the sandbox:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan
and in this page for the live mode:
https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan